# Does it make sense to think of the retarded potential solution of Maxwell's equations as a time-parity symmetry breaking solution?

Tags: electromagnetism, potential, symmetry-breaking

We know that Maxwell's theory is invariant under the transformation $T:t\rightarrow-t$. In any physical theory, this means that if you take any solution of the field equations and transform it under $T$ it will map it to **another** solution (which could be itself). In other words, the space of all solutions maps to itself under the time parity transformation $T$. This usually means that if we know one solution, we can time reverse it and it will also be a solution.

We also know that if we take the retarded potential solution and apply a time parity transformation, we end up with the advanced potential solution. **Would it make sense, then, to call the retarded solution a time-parity symmetry breaking solution?** Since it's a solution of a time symmetric theory that it is not itself time symmetric.

As a bonus question, the reason why this has nothing to do with the usual symmetry breaking theories of condensed matter or the Higgs mechanism is because time parity is a discrete symmetry instead of a continuous one, right?

Comment: Your bonus question is oddly worded. Higgs might be an especially famous example of symmetry breaking, but it's not a "default" one. The discrete-continuous distinction is just one way your example is dissimilar to Higgs, but no two examples need have "anything to do with" each other.

Answer (score 0):

The retarded green function corresponds to waves moving away from a source. The advanced describes waves coming from infinity meeting at one point, which is physically very unlikely. We say the retarded solution is the solution respecting causality. The symmetry breaking you refer at the end of your post concerns gauge theories. The local gauge symmetry of electromagentism is desceibed by the geoup $U(1)$. This means that physical quantities are invariant under change of phase. For example the Faraday tensor $F_{/mu/nu}$ is the curvature of the electromagnetic potential $A_\mu$, which is a $U(1)$ Lie algebra valued gauge connection. The quanta of this vector field we call photons. The Maxwell equations are the Bianchi identity $dF=0$. Classically this defines the moduli space of Maxwell theory. The moduli spaces consists of gauge orbits which are defined by $U(1)$ gauge transformations. The gauge fixing condition is needed to choose one solution from every orbit. The Coulomb gauge is an example. In the abelian case it corresponds to a hypersurface which intersects every gauge orbit once at the same angle.

$U(1)$ is abelian. If we generalize to non-abelian groups we can describe other forces like the weak force in the case $SU(2).$ The generators of the algebra determine the number of bosons. Turns out that the two forces are actually the same. The non-zero vacuum expectation value of the Higgs field breaks the combined symmetry group to a subgroup. This introduces new degrees of freedom for 3 of the four bosons which result in a mass term, which is proportional to the VEV of the higgs field. The one boson remaining massless we call photon. Thus it seems that we are dealing with two different forces.